# Capturar tecla pressionada usando nome ao invés de números

Tags: c#

Estou tentando capturar o valor de cada tecla em C# pelo evento KeyDown, funciona perfeitamente, mas o valor de cada é retornado por números, por exemplo ao pressionar TAB é capturado 9.

Teria uma forma de pegar o valor da tecla pelo nome, sem uso de vários ifs?

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string teclaDigitada = Convert.ToString(e.KeyValue);
        label1.Text = teclaDigitada;

        if (teclaDigitada == "38") { label2.Text = "SETA-CIMA"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "40") { label2.Text = "SETA-BAIXO"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "37") { label2.Text = "SETA-ESQUERDA"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "39") { label2.Text = "SETA-DIREITA"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "9") { label2.Text = "TAB"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "20") { label2.Text = "CAPS LOOK"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "16") { label2.Text = "SHIFT"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "17") { label2.Text = "CTRL"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "91") { label2.Text = "WINDOWS"; }
        if (teclaDigitada == "18") { label2.Text = "ALT"; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar códigos é a melhor opicão, até porque, como seria a descrição? Ia precisar fazer isso para cada língua, etc.

Mas para ajudar, existe um `emum` associado aos *KeyValues*, que ajudado para deixar o código mais legível, por exemplo:

```
if (e.KeyValue == Key.F)
```

Pode utilizar esse `enum` e pegar a sua "descrição" convertendo para string, mas como mencionei acima, vai usar os nomes na lingua que foi definida e com a nomenclatura que ele tem, mas se isso não for problema, pode ajuda a remover esses montes de `if`:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // converte para o enum (Keys)
    var keyEnum = (Keys)e.KeyValue;
    // converte para string, pegando o "nome" do enum, como Ctrl, Shift, A, B, etc
    label1.Text = keyEnum.ToString();
}
```